# How to tell if a LINQ to SQL query is translated to a SQL statement or not?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2010

We use LINQ to SQL extensively, and one of the biggest performance pitfalls we've run into is situations where a query can't be converted to SQL, and so an entire database table gets loaded into memory and the query performed by .NET. For example, this query

```
Dim Foo = (From c in Db.Contacts Select c Where c.ContactID=MyContactID)
```

translates to a simple SQL query, whereas

```
Dim Foo = (From c in Db.Contacts Select c Where c.ContactID=SafeInt(MyContactID))
```

doesn't because SafeInt is our own function and doesn't have a SQL equivalent; so the whole contacts table gets loaded into memory and searched by LINQ to objects, which is vastly slower.

With a little experience, we've gotten better at avoiding this kind of situation. But it's not always obvious, and this is the sort of problem that's often not revealed until you're working with a lot of data and things start to slow down.

Is there a straightforward way to see - whether in Visual Studio or some other way - how LINQ queries will be handled, other than trial and error?

Comment: Based on my (limited) understanding of Linq, if you explicitly set the type of the filter function to an `Expression<Func<T,Bool>>` instead of a `Func<T,Bool>`, it should be able to translate it into SQL, or at the least give a runtime error, so that you know it's not loading everything in memory. cf http://stackoverflow.com/a/26617875/712526

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)? That is a fantastic Linq prototyping tool. I often use it to prototype my Linq queries, before pasting them into my code. The tool is free.

Are you also aware that you can convert an IQueryable (which gets sent to SQL Server) to an IEnumerable, in order to have the query processed by the .NET Framework, instead of SQL Server? I'll sometimes to do this if I need to call one of my own methods in a Linq query. I'll break the query up into two parts. The first part I'll query as an IEnumerable, and the other part as an IQueryable, and then join the two together.

Comment: Thanks - LinqPad is great, but it doesn't really work in more complex situations, for example where a query has references to our own code.

Comment: Did you know you can reference your own assemblies in LinqPad?

Answer (score 0):

[**L2SProf (LINQ to SQL Profiler)**](http://l2sprof.com/) is another option that could help you track down the inefficient queries.  It has a series of alerts such as [*Excessive Number of Rows Returned*](http://l2sprof.com/Learn/Alerts/ExcessiveNumberOfRows) and [*Unbounded Result Set*](http://l2sprof.com/Learn/Alerts/UnboundedResultSet), and so on.  I've found it to be helpful for troubleshooting problems like you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
Sub Main
    Dim c = From a In Context.Addresses 
            Where a.City = "London" 
            Select a

    Console.Write(Context.GetCommand(c).CommandText)
End Sub
```

This should reveal the SQL query that will get used.

Comment: Right - even simpler (as I recently discovered) you can just do c.ToString to get the SQL query. What I was hoping for was a way to see this in Visual Studio while coding, rather than while debugging - presumably the compiler knows how any given query will need to be executed.